# How to make the cut penetrate the entire model？

Tags: modeling

[image]

Thanks~ This picture shows what I want. I don't know how to describe it use.
Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with using a  boolean?

Comment: The K knife tool has a 'Cut Through' option, activated by hitting Z.

Comment: I think that all he needs is Ctrl+R and S+X+0 to make it like on that picture

Comment: Ctrl R won't work if your edge loop meets a tri or an ngon, so as Robin says, use the knife to cut through

Comment: apologies, I thought you wanted to remove everything to the right of your drawn loop